# Crossrider - Multiple Browser Buttons

Tags: cross-browser, crossrider

Any way of creating multiple browser buttons with Crossrider?

I know it is probably far-fetched from the documentation I have read, but nevertheless worth the question if anyone else has the need or has managed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Crossrider framework is enables each extension to have at most one browser action or page action as we believe multiple buttons are annoying the users. This is also in line with [Chrome's extension policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) of one action per extension.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]